# Weird margin behavior for display: block vs display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, margin

I still dont understand margins well, even after years

sometimes they work, sometimes they dont. Are there any simple rules?

for example I had this:

[image]

this is a block element inside of a bootstrap `.container`

as you can see, the top margin works, the bottom margin doesnt.

If I switch the `display: block;` of that all rights reserved element to `display: inline-block;` it starts working.

[image]

why is that?

Comment: TL;DR : margin collpasing doesn't happen with inline-block, only with block

Comment: Everything is detailed here if you have time to read it: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins .. you will probably need to read it more than once to understand all the cases

Comment: @TemaniAfif the document you linked is really unreadable to me. Can you add a short summary as answer maybe? as the "duplicate" questions link to that unreadable document as well with no easy answer

Comment: I added two duplicates dealing with the same issue and you don't have to read that document. It's the official specification with all the accurate detail and I know it's not trivial to read it but now you know what you are facing and you have a name for it (margin collapsing) and this is your answer. Now simply google that word and you will find a lot of articles with figures that will illustrate and explain it using easy words. There is also more question in SO talking about if you follow the two duplicate I added